# How to fix needing to reload my api in nuxt every time i change my api?

Tags: node.js, api, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I connected an express api to the nuxt `servermiddleware: ['~/api/index']` in the nuxt.config.js file. but if i'm dev building my api, i don't want to reload the dev server manually every single time i change something in the code (that costs a lot of time). It looks like the api runs independent from the nuxt.js website. if the website reloads, the api won't and the changes will not show. Is there a way that the api reloads when the website reloads?

my code in the index.js of the api is this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Require API routes
const company = require('./routes/company')

// Import API Routes
app.use('/company', company)

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
    path: '/api',
    handler: app
}
```

i hope its more clear now.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. What do you mean by _"change a route in my node.js API"_? If you change the API URLs, anything using the old ones will have to update. What do you mean by _"reload the whole Nuxt.js website"_? Do you mean you have to hit "reload" in the browser or do you mean a re-build?

Comment: yes sorry, it's unclear. i have an express api connected to the servermiddleware from nuxt.js. if i change something in the code of the api. i need to restart my nuxt dev server. It looks like it works a bit independent from the nuxt.js website. is there any solution that my api reloads when my nuxt website does too?

Comment: I'd suggest finishing your API first, at least the external-facing contracts / interfaces

Comment: _"i have an express api connected to the servermiddleware from nuxt.js"_  can you please show some code that explains this? It's still unclear why you need to restart you dev server

Comment: in my nuxt.config.js file i can add this code: serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/index'
  ], but if i'm debugging or dev building my api, it will cost a long time restarting the server every single time. that's why i want a solution for auto restarting the api when i change something to it. otherwise it will not implement my new code.

Comment: Please add code to your question, not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

In the components folder edit your config to be like

```
{ 
  // this avoids reloading all components every time you run the app
  components: false
}
```